# python-social-auth patterns errors

Tags: django, python-social-auth

I downloaded python-social-auth from github and tried to use but I encounter an error when I try to install patterns packet.
I'm using the last version of django and the last version of python.
I've read that patterns is no longer available with python 3.x.
Here patterns package is used:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 'example.app.views.home'),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^email-sent/', 'example.app.views.validation_sent'),
    url(r'^login/$', 'example.app.views.home'),
    url(r'^logout/$', 'example.app.views.logout'),
    url(r'^done/$', 'example.app.views.done', name='done'),
    url(r'^ajax-auth/(?P<backend>[^/]+)/$', 'example.app.views.ajax_auth',
        name='ajax-auth'),
    url(r'^email/$', 'example.app.views.require_email', name='require_email'),
    url(r'', include('social.apps.django_app.urls', namespace='social'))
)
```

I tried to delete patterns and put [ ... ] but it doesn't work. Any suggestion?

[image]

Comment: Did you read the [release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/releases/1.8/#django-conf-urls-patterns)? If you still can't get it to work, include the error message and traceback in your post, because "it doesn't work" is incredibly unhelpful.

Comment: I cannot run patterns on python 3.x. This is my problem. pip fails to install